# how to access singleton objects inside Workmanager.executeTask's callback using flutter-workmanager

Tags: flutter, flutter-workmanager

Creating `List<String> mainList` globally and adding one item in `main()` function. But inside the Workmanager.executeTask's callback mainList's lenth is still 0. Even the hashCode of the mainList is different.

- Why this is happening?
- How make the mainList as Singleton?
- Tried printing the `Isolate.current.debugName`, it's always 'main'.

```
List<String> mainList=[];
void callbackDispatcher() {
  Workmanager.executeTask((task, inputData) {
    print("mainList.length=${mainList.length}"); // always length is 0
    print("Isolate.current.debugName = ${Isolate.current.debugName}");
    return Future.value(true);
  });
}

void main() {
  Workmanager.initialize(
    callbackDispatcher,
    isInDebugMode: true,
  );
  mainList.add("String1");
  print("mainList.length=${mainList.length}"); // length is 1
  print("Isolate.current.debugName = ${Isolate.current.debugName}");
  Workmanager.registerPeriodicTask("1", "simpleTask");
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Comment: Why not set the `inputData` when calling `Workmanager.registerPeriodicTask(...)`? Sample: `inputData: <String, List<String>>{'data': mainList},`

Comment: yeah can do that, but Why the mainList's hashcode changes(why list created again newly)? And how to access other singleton objects not just a List, something like socket or other objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `ListenableWorker.startWork()` a new FlutterEngin instance is created every time and executing `Workmanager.executeTask`'s `callback`.

**So no way for using singleton objects.**

[BackgroundWorker.kt](https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_workmanager/blob/master/android/src/main/kotlin/be/tramckrijte/workmanager/BackgroundWorker.kt)